# laravel Livewire wire:click not firing the function

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, typescript, laravel-livewire

I want to do a SPA with laravel livewire, i want to use wire:click to fire a funtion in the component but it not working , excuse me if the code mess its my first time posting here and i am not sure of what to post here of my code to make these problem solve thank you

main.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card my-3">

                        <!-- header -->
                <div class="card-header d-inline-flex">
                    <h3 class='mr-2'>Categories</h3>
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" wire:click='createCategory' class="btn btn-success ">Add NewCategory</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- header -->
                <div class="card-body">

                    <!-- alerts -->
                    @include('admin.includes.alerts.errors')
                    @include('admin.includes.alerts.success')
                    <!-- alerts -->


                    <!-- if True , create form will show , if not will stay disabled -->
                    @if ($showCreateForm)
                    @livewire('admin.category.create' )
                    @endif
                    <!-- if True , create form will show , if not will stay disabled -->

                    <!-- Table -->
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Slug</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Parent</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
                                    {{-- <td>{{storage_path(app\livewire-tmp\$category->image)}}" /></td> --}}
                                    <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$category->slug}}</td>
                                    <td class=" {{$category->isActive()==='Active'? 'text-success':'text-danger'}}">
                                        {{$category->isActive()}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ !empty($category->parent) ? $category->parent->name:'' }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Slug</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Parent</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                        <div>
                            {!!$categories->links()!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Table -->

                </div><!-- body -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and The Component Main.php ,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Category;

use App\Models\Admin\Category;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Main extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $categories;
    public $showCreateForm = false;
    public $showEditForm = false;
    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(12);
        return view('livewire.admin.category.main',[
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]) ->layout('layouts.admin');
    }

    public function createCategory()
    {
         $this->showCreateForm = !$this->showCreateForm;
    }
    public function update_Category($id)
    {


         $categories = Category::whereId($id);
         if ($categories) {
            $this->emit('getCategoryid' , $categories);
            $this->showEditForm = !$this->showEditForm;
            $this->showCreateForm = false;
         }
    }
    public function delete_Category($id)
    {
         $this->showCreateForm = !$this->showCreateForm;
    }
}
```

- //// **Update** ////

i tried iRestWeb Answer, I think it the right answer but i dont even understand what happening its 100% javascript related and its not my field of expertise , so here's my full code i hope some one understand , and again sorry if my code messy and give you hard time , thank youu.

create.blade.php

```html
<div>
  <form role="form" wire:submit.prevent="create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Parent</label>
            <select type="select" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" wire:model="parent_id" name="parent_id">
              <option selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
              {{-- @if (is_array($categories) || is_object($categories) || !empty($categories)) --}} @foreach ($categories as $category)
              <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
              @endforeach {{-- @endif --}}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Category Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" wire:model="name" name="name"> @error('name') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Slug Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" wire:model="slug" name="slug"> @error('slug') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Image</label>
            <input type="file" wire:model="image" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="image"> @error('image') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- 4 -->
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" wire:model="is_active" name="is_active">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">is Active</label> @error('is_active') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Create.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Category;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Admin\Category;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;



class Create extends Component
{


use WithFileUploads;
    use WithPagination;

    public $slug , $name , $image , $parent_id , $is_active;

    protected $rules = [
        'slug' => 'required|unique:categories,slug',
        'name' => 'required',
        'image'=> 'nullable|image|max:1024'
    ];

    protected $categories;
    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(12);
        return view('livewire.admin.category.create' , [
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $data = [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'is_active'=> $this->is_active,
            'image'=> $this->image,
            'parent_id'=> $this->parent_id,
        ];
        //image upload
            try {
                if ($image = $this->image) {
                    $filename = Str::slug($this->name).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $path = public_path('assets/image/'.$filename);
                    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path,100);
                }
                Category::create($data);
                $this->reset();
                return $this->addError('success' , 'Created Successfuly');
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                return $this->addError('error', 'Something Wrong Happens');
            }

    }

}
```

edit.blade.php

```html
<div>
  <form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit.prevent="update">
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Parent</label>
            <select type="select" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" wire:model="parent_id" name="parent_id">
              <option></option>
              {{-- @if (is_array($categories) || is_object($categories) || !empty($categories)) --}} @foreach ($categories as $category)
              <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
              @endforeach {{-- @endif --}}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Category Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" wire:model="name" value='{{$category->name}}' name="name"> @error('name') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Slug Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" wire:model="slug" name="slug" value='{{$category->slug}}'> @error('slug') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="image">
            <img value='{{$category->image}}' alt="" srcset=""> @error('image') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- 4 -->
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" wire:model="is_active" name="is_active">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">is Active</label> @error('is_active') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Edit.php (uncompleted Task)

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Category;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Admin\Category;

class Edit extends Component
{
    protected $categories , $cat_id;
    public $slug , $name , $image , $old_image , $parent_id , $is_active;

    protected $listeners = ['getCategoryid'=>'getID'];


    public function mount()
    {
       $this->categories = Category::whereId($this->cat_id)->first();
    }//mout


    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.category.edit' , [
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }//render

    public function update($id)
    {

    }//update

    public function getID($categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;

        // Data
        $this->slug = $this->$categories['slug'];
        $this->name = $this->$categories['name'];
        $this->image = $this->$categories['image'];
        $this->old_image = $this->$categories['old_image'];
        $this->parent_id = $this->$categories['parent_id'];
        $this->is_active = $this->$categories['is_active'];

    }//getID
}
```

Comment: welcome to so, what do you mean by not working, tell more about the error which is showing

Comment: the link in the card header should go and run the function in the Main.php component , so when i click on it it doesn't do anything

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Nothing happens in network , and no errors in console

Comment: check the network tab, is it sending any thing?

Comment: Can anyone have a look here please! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71357968/urgent-laravel-livewire-not-getting-form-dara-on-create-order

Comment: Adding one more possible solution, it could be you are dealing with nested forms. The nested form will have their submit button overridden by the main form. Thus, not submitting your intended form.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

All HTML code should be covered with single `<div>.` Then it will work.

Comment: You made my day! Thank you

Comment: Worked perfectly, is this in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: Wow, this solved my issue as well - thanks

Comment: Bro, this is most stupid problem i have meet in my entire life, THANK YOU. <3

Comment: I wasted hours trying to get my code working, all because I had put a <h2> at the top.  It is incredible that such a basic error gives no clues to the cause, it just totally disables Livewire with no messages.

Comment: Almost one year after still this answer saving lives :D

Comment: love you man <3

Answer (score 3):

add liveWire's css and js in the base.blade.php file and it works:

```
<head>
...
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    ...

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```html
<a href="#" wire:click.prevent="$toggle('showCreateForm')" class="btn btn-success">Add New Category</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `:click` event to do this, you can simply use:

```
wire:$toggle('property')
```

And you don't need to use the `a` tag; you can simply use the `button` tag. So your button code will look like this:

```html
<button type="button" wire:$toggle='showCreateForm' class="btn btn-success">Add New Category</button>
```

Comment: thank you for replying , i will try it and aprove if it works or not

Comment: it didn't work buddy , i think its javascript thing because it dont respond at all like a disabled link it odd very odd

Comment: Did you include the livewire's css & js ? please provide the full code of the page including the layout page

Answer (score -1):

use <livewire:styles /> and <livewire:scripts />
(instead @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts)

Answer (score -1):

Run this command

```
$ php artisan serve
```

That means running the port

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/

It will work fine.

When the url is http://localhost/project-name/public/ Button wire:clike is not firing.