# wire:click not firing method in its component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am trying to implement Logout functionality on my Laravel app with TALL stack, I am firing logout event from my blade via Livewire `wire:click` but it doesn't seem to fire any method from its own component.

Loading my component in app.blade.php layout:

```
<li class="flex">
   @livewire('logout')
</li>
```

logout.blade.php

```
<a
    wire:click="logout"
    class="some-classes"
>
    <svg
        class="w-4 h-4 mr-3"
        aria-hidden="true"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
    >
        <path d=""></path>
    </svg>
    <span>Log out</span>
</a>
```

Logout.php (Livewire Component)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class Logout extends Component
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin-panel.logout');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $this->redirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

I have tried `dump` inside function and it turned out that the methods are not being called. I have sigle root `<a></a>` in component's view, using `<div>` doen't make any difference either.

I used `<button>` in place of `<a>` and it didn't work either. I wonder what I could possibly be doing wrong here. If there's any other way of doing this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: wire:click.prevent

Comment: Do you have any console warnings or errors? Is Livewire loaded properly?

Comment: @Qirel as mentioned above, console shows nothing, dumping inside the `logout` doesn't work either. Simply saying once rendered it nevers calls any of methods from component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the button was having an default behavior and needed `wire:click.prevent`

in my `logout.blade.php`:

```
<a
    wire:click.prevent="logout" // here
    class="some-classes"
>
    <svg
        class="w-4 h-4 mr-3"
        aria-hidden="true"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
    >
        <path d=""></path>
    </svg>
    <span>Log out</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you include livewire assets and livewire scripts.

You should see this answers from similar question:

[first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66255038/8968121),
[second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64092232/8968121).

the solution for this error is usually the first answer. try like that, maybe that helps:

```
<li class="flex">
    <div>
       @livewire('logout')
    </div>
</li>
```

and

```
<div>
  <a
    wire:click="logout"
    class="some-classes"
>
    <svg
        class="w-4 h-4 mr-3"
        aria-hidden="true"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
    >
        <path d=""></path>
    </svg>
    <span>Log out</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a div. It just need to be one root element, which is already the case.

Comment: As already mentioned, and as per livewire docs, it has to be a single root element, and for  solutions you suggested, I have already tried similar solutions if you look at the question closely.